# Javascript object's function returns undefined or always false?

Tags: javascript, function, object, comparison

Okay, so I'm pretty sure I'm just dumb as hell as I'm new to javascript.
Tried to finde anything, but didn't. Probably because I don't know at all what I could be looking for.

I got an array filled with different data. I think they're all stored as strings, as I get them from a XMLHttpRequest of a website's search.

```
var search = document.getElementById("filter").value;
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', "https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks?client_id=1dff55bf515582dc759594dac5ba46e9&q=" + search, false);
xhr.addEventListener("load", function() {
    var searchString = xhr.response;

    searchArray = searchString.split(",");
```

I then try to store some of the array's data in an object's different porperties. For one of the properties, I try to check two places in the array and compare then. For some reason it won't work:

```
track01  = 
{..., usable:function(){if(searchArray[37] === "true" && searchArray[19] === "all"){return true;}else{return false;}}, ...};
```

**This always returns false, even if it should be true.**

*I also tried it with == or without the quotation marks. (On either side and both sides)*

Another thing I tried was to get rid of the if / else:

```
track01  = 
{..., usable:function(){searchArray[37] == "true" && searchArray[19] == "all"};
```

**This always returns undefined for some reason.**

To be clear: searchArray[37] is a string with the content "true" and searchArray[19] a string with the content "all". At least in the case I'm testing.

I hope this isn't as dumb as I think it is.

Comment: `searchArray = searchString.split(",");` — What on earth are you doing? Hint: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse

Comment: In general, to debug this sort of problem, you should `console.log(searchArray[37])` to see what the value is (hint: There is a lot more to it than the word "true"), but as noted in my previous comment, your entire approach is wrong.

Comment: @Quentin I thought this is how you do it. The search result is one giant string and I split it at every "," to get one big array so I can call all the elements by one. There is no "," used except to split different properties in the SoundCloud search.

Comment: @Quentin Okay, I'm new to javascript and willing to learn. I thought I was on the right path. What am I doing so terribly wrong?

Comment: @Quentin console.log returns "true", for real. Only the word and nothing else

Answer (score 0):

What @Quentin is saying is that the soundcloud api returns a JSON object and you should parse it as such - Not by split().

That being said it still does not explain your error. If both searchArray[37]  and searchArray[19] are indeed just the strings "true" and "all", then something else is wrong. Try to post your actual code for creating the track01 object and how you use the usable property.